# Read CSV file and output results as HTML list

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I am trying to read in a CSV file using PapaParse and then output it as a html list.  I have this so far...

```
document.getElementById('txtFileUpload').addEventListener('change', upload, false);

 function upload(evt) {

    var data = null;
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var csvData = event.target.result;
        var data = Papa.parse(csvData, {header : true});

        console.log(data.data);

        var arrayLength = data.data.length;
        console.log(arrayLength);
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            console.log(data.data[i]);
            $("#header").append("<li>" + data.data[i] + "</li>");
        }

    };
    reader.onerror = function() {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
    };  

}
```

This works but each list item outputs as [object Object].  Where am I going wrong?

My console output looks like this...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of *objects*, thus when you do

```js
"<li>" + data.data[i] + "</li>"
```

those objects are converted to strings. Plain object's `toString` representation is `[object Object]`.

From your question it's unclear what do you expect, so you could either get object's `apple` field:

```js
"<li>" + data.data[i].apple + "</li>"
```

or use `JSON` representation of this object:

```js
"<li>" + JSON.stringify(data.data[i]) + "</li>"
```